# Strange Swift Protocol behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift-protocols

Having trouble using a swift protocol to simplify UIPageViewController:

I have this protocol

```
protocol Pagable {
    var pageIndex: Int? { get set }
}
```

which I have all of my UIViewControllers being presented by the UIPageViewController conform to.

Then in my UIPageViewController, I do this:

```
var vc = StoryboardScene.Challenges.acceptedViewController() as! Pagable   
vc.pageIndex = index
return vc as? UIViewController
```

which works, but what I really want to do is:

```
var vc = StoryboardScene.Challenges.acceptedViewController()
(vc as? Pagable)?.pageIndex = index
return vc
```

and for some reason, whenever I do that instead (which to me feels exactly the same as snippet 1), I get an error on the `(vc as? Pagable)?.pageIndex = index` saying that "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type `Int?`".

I'm thoroughly confused. Would love some insight into why the type system is doing this to me.

Comment: try `if let vc = StoryboardScene.Challenges.acceptedViewController() as? Pagable { vc.pageIndex = index; return vc }`

Comment: If *have all of my UIViewControllers … conform to* what's the purpose of using optional bindings ? And why is `pageIndex` optional ?

Comment: I understand what I was trying to do wasn't best practice, refactored to a better way of doing it (turning `pageIndex` into a constant and assigning in the child VC). But I'd still like to understand why `(vc as? Pagable)?.pageIndex = index` isn't allowed

Comment: This should work, as you're using optional chaining, which doesn't deal with mutability/immutability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
var vc = StoryboardScene.Challenges.acceptedViewController()
(vc as? Pagable)?.pageIndex = index
```

`vc` is a variable, but `(vc as? Pagable)` is an immutable expression.

The solution is to declare a "class-only protocol":

```
protocol Pagable : class {
    var pageIndex: Int? { get set }
}
```

Then the compiler knows that all conforming types are *reference types*,
so that the property can be assigned to even if the reference itself
is constant.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, thanks! Is `(vc as? Pagable)` shorthand for `if let` syntax?

Comment: @AndrewSB: No. As I understand it, the `as?` operator returns a new (immutable) expression. Here is a simpler example: `var x = 123 ; x = 456` compiles, but `var x = 123 ; (x as Int) = 456` does not.